# Breaking anaconda's twitter stream when needed

Tags: go, twitter, anaconda, channel, goroutine

I have a bit of code that listen to twitter's live tweets containing a particular word (here "obama" for the example) and prints them using the anaconda package (https://github.com/ChimeraCoder/anaconda).

I want to be able to shut down the stream of tweets at a given moment when I call an other function. In order to do this, I tried to have a channel called "stop" that whenever it receive a value, the program stops listening to the stream.

I tried the following code to stop the stream after 10 seconds of execution :

```
    func main() {
            trackingArray := []string{ "obama"}

            anaconda.SetConsumerKey(consumerKey)
            anaconda.SetConsumerSecret(consumerSecret)

            api := anaconda.NewTwitterApi(accessToken, accessTokenSecret)

            stream := api.PublicStreamFilter(url.Values{
                        "track":    trackingArray,
            })

            stop := make(chan int)

            for {
                select {
                    case v := <- stream.C :
                        tweet, ok := v.(anaconda.Tweet)
                        if !ok {
                            /* handle incorrect type */
                            continue
                        }

                        fmt.Print(tweet)

                    case <- stop :
                        stream.Stop()
                        break

                    }
                }

           go After(&stop)
    }

    func After(stop *chan int){
        time.Sleep(time.Second * 10)
        *stop <- 1
    }
```

This code doesn't work at all and the stream never stops...

My stop channel should be reusable as the goal behind this would be that it act as a on/off toggle to start/stop listening to twitter's stream.

It may be a newbie question but I thought I had understood how channels work and I'm kinda lost here...
Thanks in advance for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are starting the gouroutine `go After(&stop)` **after** the `for` loop, which the goroutine needs to break. That results in the loop never get broken and the gouroutine never starts.

To fix it, simply put `go After(&stop)` before the `for` loop.